# Zipkin - Distributed tracing

Tags: java, instrumentation, trace, zipkin

I have several services. I am instrumenting them using Zipkin.

In each module, in build.gradle is added a dependency to Zipkin:

```
 compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-zipkin')
```

In each module, in application.properties file are following settings:

```
spring.application.name=moduleX
spring.sleuth.sampler.percentage=0.2
spring.zipkin.base-url=http://localhost:9412
```

I call a specific endpoint that use other 3 modules, in total are 4 modules. Entire setup is on my laptop. I realized that Zipkin introduces a lot of overhead. I used Mozilla to compare the results. The small values are when Zipkin does not record the requests and the big value is when Zipkin records.

[image]
Do you have any idea why there are so much overhead?
Thank you.

Comment: Did you check this with different sample rates?

Answer (score 1):

1.You should check if your Zipkin Server is on.

2.You should check if the Span transfering is async.

In HTTP,Zipkin uses in-band transfer,all the information carried in HTTP headers.The cost time of generating Span is about 200 nanosecond.